# Resize program already programmed in IDLE

Tags: python, tkinter

I programmed in Python an application a couple of years ago in my computer, however I replaced the computer and now my application doesn't fit the screen.

All windows, labels and buttons were placed using coordinates:

```
window.geometry("1700x1010")
Label(VentanaCGR, text='"', justify="left").place(x=335, y= 60)
```

Do I need to rearrange everything or is there any way to fit it to the screen regardles the computer resolution configuratio?

Comment: You need to rearrange everything.

Comment: This is a tkinter, not an IDLE question.  Use the pack or grid geometry managers and your application is more likely to adjust to different screen sizes automatically.  Or use a window small enough to fit on any desktop screen.

Comment: You can specify the positions in other ways, so that positions will adapt to the resolution; but since everything is currently a hard-coded position, you will still need to change everything. In any event, this is a broad topic, beyond the scope of a single Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. Is there any way to make the windows scrollable, so that I can use the existing program (giving me some time to modify it later). Currently, the program is shown trimmed, but if I could scroll the window I could still use it.